# Why does my release mode Rust executable contain strings with absolute path names?

Tags: rust, exe, compiler-optimization, rust-cargo

I just built my first Rust hello world program followed by a websocket client, compiled with:

```
cargo build --release
```

Scouring the `216 KB` executable inside `hello_cargo\target\release` with a hex editor I see:

```
C:\\Users\\GirkovArpa\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecd2293db9ea513\\embedded-websocket-0.3.0\\src\\lib.rs
```

```
C:\\Users\\GirkovArpa\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecd2293db9ea513\\heapless-0.5.5\\src\\string.rs
```

```
C:\\Users\\GirkovArpa\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecd2293db9ea513\\rand-0.7.3\\src\\rngs\\thread.rs
```

```
C:\\Users\\GirkovArpa\\Documents\\GitHub\\hello_cargo\\target\\release\\deps\\hello_cargo.pdb
```

And a couple more strings like this.  And this is after running `strip hello_cargo.exe`.

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Debugging symbols aren't the only source for this. The strings you pasted most likely come from error-paths which include them as part of their backtrace (think `.unwrap()`). In fact, any piece of code - including stdlib or dependencies - can call the [`std::file!`-macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.file.html) and if it's not proven to be dead, the string will get included in the final executable. So if privacy is of high concern to you, the only reliable way is to build inside a virtual machine.

Comment: What dependencies do you use?

Answer (score 3):

This is a big problem for distributed compilation / caching. I would suggest following [this issue](https://github.com/mozilla/sccache/issues/35). They suggest using `--remap-path-prefix`. Docs [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/command-line-arguments.html#--remap-path-prefix-remap-source-names-in-output).

[People are working on first class support for this.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3127)